Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated
i'm a newbie at this and im trying to set laravel sail to my laptop using ubuntu terminal. there's no problem in installation but when i use the command sudo ./vendor/bin/sail up
i get this error:

Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint exapp-mysql-1 (8b37fca8d11d52f0456d65180990c572d9d7b39a54944845ee6ba7f1634a2d59): Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated

i know i need to change the port that it selects and tried to find ways in many blogs but couldnt seem to find a solution that solves my problem yet.
i tried to get rid of zombie process', tried to stop container and deleting it, i tried restarting docker but they didn't solve my problem. i'd appreciate any idea and help i could get.

Does this help? docker mysql on different port

Could you share your Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file.

@CBroe i just tried it but it doesn't help either

If you are using docker-compose.yml you can use "ports" under the service that you want to configure, like:
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3006"

Just change the port "3307" for some port that is available on your laptop and change if necessary the port "3306" to match port(s) that your container is using.
The line - "3307:3306" under ports tells Docker to bind the port 3306 of the nginx:alpine service (inside the Docker container) to the port 3307 of the host machine. This means that the nginx:alpine service will be accessible at localhost:8080 on your host machine.

This is a multi step fix

Run docker ps and see what containers are running.
Stop the container running on the port  docker stop {name}
./vendor/bin/sail up to restart the service

If you find it still giving you a bind error it's likely your running MySQL/MariaDB or equivalent on your local system in which case you will need to stop those services before restarting
